# How to download a pdf instead of sending it per email?

Tags: civimail, pdf

I'm sending a membership certificate attached to an email template with Drupal 7 / CiviCRM using CiviRules and PdfApi but often the emails don't reach the recipients because of deliverability issues, even though I use a professional SMTP gateway.

I'm wondering about sending a link to the pdf instead of sending the pdf attached. Is this possible knowing that members don't have access to CiviCRM, they have no User account?

Any experience with this topic?

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a page and based on cid, checksum and mid using pdfapi would recreate the pdf to download (via extension)

Comment: thanks Pradeep. I hope to fix this deliverability issue first, if no I'll try your solution

Comment: may be the size of the pdf is a issue

Comment: they are both light, around 30ko.